# What is the correct link to open a video in YouTube studio?

Tags: android, google-chrome, youtube

What is the correct link to open YouTube studio? This kind of link works in Chrome on Windows 10, but not on Android 10:

```html
<a href="https://studio.youtube.com/video/${ytId}/edit">Open video in YouTube Studio</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

As of for your knowledge their is no such web link through which you can access YouTube Studio from Android but you can get it in:

- The basic version through the [dashboard](https://m.youtube.com/dashboard).
- Or switch to desktop site option on Chrome Android — it's a browser option &8212; and then try to use the [YouTube Studio Link](https://studio.youtube.com/channel/). It will definitely work.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. However those two links also works on Windows 10, but not on Android 10. They open YouTube Studio on Windows, but the normal YouTube on Android. (And they also do not take me to the video.)

Comment: Eh, my bad. They work the way you said. But it is unfortunately not what I need. As you surely know... 

Comment: So I guess you also have investigated this a bit. Looks like it is not implemented yet on Android.

Comment: Hm, and in the latest version of Chrome for Android that just arrived you can no longer view the mobile version of YouTube. :-(

Comment: This last problem with YouTube was some strange problem with cookies on my Android. (Propably a YouTube bug according the the chromium devs.)